# I am not able to paste text in React-Quill Editor on Safari

Tags: react-quill

I am not able to PASTE text on React-Quill Editor on Safari(Only) While I am able to COPY , CUT, REDO and UNDO the text using shortcut keys.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `-webkit-user-select: text` to the `.ql-clipboard` `div` element

```
.ql-clipboard {
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I used `user-select: none;` in a parent div